# "Малоболезненная" или "мало болезненная"?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

*Малоболезненная* или *мало болезненная* процедура ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Малоболезненный - медицинский термин, который чаще пишется слитно, например:

Процедура **малоболезненная** и хорошо переносится пациентами. Процедура **малоболезненная** и не требует специальной анестезии. Морфологической основой является плотный **болезненный или малоболезненный** ограниченный инфильтрат в околоушной области.

В то ж время термин - структура неустойчивая и может распадаться на наречие и прилагательное (обычно под влиянием зависимых слов):

В области угла нижней челюсти лимфатический узел, увеличенный до размеров голубиного яйца, **мало болезненный при пальпации**..

Answer (score 1):

Корректно: малоболезненный.

мало... - как первая часть сложных слов пишется слитно, но: мало-мальски, мало-помалу

> См.: Слитно или раздельно? Орфографический словарь-справочник. — М.: Русский язык. Б. З. Букчина, Л. П. Какалуцкая. 1998.
>
> Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук.
> Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин.

Answer (score -1):

Тут сильно зависит от смысла, от контекста. Да, вариант "малоболезненый" вполне возможен как термин, как понятие. Если болезненный, но мало - то раздельно.

Примерно по тому же принципу, что и с "не". Если это новое понятие - то слитно, если малое качество исходного (редко, но возможно) - раздельно.

Когда-то умный и ироничный писатель Владимир Алексеевич Солоухин (один из немногих настоящих интеллигентов, почему-то записанных в "деревенщики"), обыграл эту тему, назвав улицу Малую Советскую "малосоветской". Почувствуйте разницу. Тоже и с "болезненностью".

Короче, давайте контекст, посмотрим. Императивность Сержа меня лично совершенно не устраивает.

Comment: "Но если..." - ?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, спасибо, восстановил пропавшее.

Comment: Не за что)*****